# News ticker with moving text from left to right

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, marquee

I am trying to make a rss news ticker which will display the text,the text need move from left to right

[image]

I made the the code and text is moving from left to right but after a specific time its not showing the full text,i will be adding more news from the admin pannel,each time i add the news the text is not showing after the first scroll

the below screenshot is after a specific amount of time,only a part of news is displaying
[image]

Code used

```
int x = -800,y=1;
this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            label1.SetBounds(x, y, 1, 1);
            x++;
            if(x>=800)
            {
                x = 4;
            }

        }
```

Code for reading xml

```
private void StartRssThread()
        {
            List<RssChannel> channels = new List<RssChannel>();
            StringBuilder mergedFeed =  new StringBuilder();
            int mh = 0;


                int ms = 0;
                if (mh < 7)
                {
                    RssFeed DaFeed = RssFeed.Read("http://shjc.ae/rss/fileName.xml");
                    RssChannel DaChannel = (RssChannel)DaFeed.Channels[0];
                    channels.Add(DaChannel);
                    mergedFeed.AppendFormat(" {0}: ", DaChannel.Title);

                    foreach (RssItem sTrm in DaChannel.Items)
                    {
                        if (ms < 10)
                        {
                            mergedFeed.AppendFormat(" {0} |", sTrm.Title);
                            ms++;
                            mh++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            string dafeed = mergedFeed.ToString();
            mergedFeed = null;
            textBox1.Invoke(new UpdateUiCallback(this.UpdateUi), new string[] { dafeed });

        }
```

Comment: The question is marked with "asp.net" and "winforms" tags, which does not make much sense. Are you working on a web application (asp.net) or desktop one (winforms)?

Comment: [Windows Forms Marquee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54272427/3110834)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using hard coded values for the start and max value of x. From your question I think the text in the label has a dynamic length (correct?). If the text is of dynamic length the value of x should also be dynamic.

Also, x starts at -800. Then slowly grows to 800 and then it gets set to 4.
This seems strange to me, if the first run started at -800, the second run may also need to start at -800.

Hope this somewhat helped you. If not, please provide more details (like why you chose -800, 800 and 4).

Comment: you are right,how can i get the length of the text which i am adding from backend

Comment: @riz I think `TextRenderer.MeasureText( text, textBox1.Font );` should do it. Not sure but you can look up that function for more information

Comment: is it possible to add different images? how could i do it?

Answer (score 6):

### Windows Forms Marquee Label - Horizontal

I've already posted an example of how to create a Marquee Label to animate text from top to bottom, by using a `Timer` and overriding `OnPaint` method of a custom draw control in this post: [Windows Forms Top to Bottom Marquee Label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54272427/3110834).

In the following code, I've changed that example to animates the text horizontally from right to left or left to right. It's enough to set `RightToLeft` property of the control to change the direction. Also don't forget to set `AutoSize` to `false`.

[image]

**Example - Right to Left and Left to Right Marquee Label in Windows Forms**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MarqueeLabel : Label
{
    Timer timer;
    public MarqueeLabel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        timer = new Timer() { Interval = 100 };
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }
    int? left;
    int textWidth = 0;
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
        {
            left += 3;
            if (left > Width)
                left = -textWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            left -= 3;
            if (left < -textWidth)
                left = Width;
        }
        Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);
        var s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text, Font, new Size(0, 0),
            TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | TextFormatFlags.SingleLine);
        textWidth = s.Width;
        if (!left.HasValue) left = Width;
        var format = TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | TextFormatFlags.SingleLine |
            TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
        if (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
        {
            format |= TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft;
            if (!left.HasValue) left = -textWidth;
        }
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font,
            new Rectangle(left.Value, 0, textWidth, Height),
            ForeColor, BackColor, format);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            timer.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good enough to start. Later you can extend the control by adding a few properties to setup the movement step (instead of +=3 or -=3) or the movement interval (instead of 100 ms) or reset the animation on text change and some other properties.

Comment: Just in case you wanted to extend the control, you can force `Label` to set `AutoSize = false` when you drop an instance of the control on form. To do so, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353592/3110834).