# How to make RichTextBox AutoScroll Horizontally

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a Windows Form in VS2019 with C#.

I have a Gradient colored rectangle box and I put a RichTextBox on it.
The only thing now is that I need the text in it to automatically scroll horizontally. Like a News Bar!

Is there a way to do that??

Comment: What's a 'news bar'?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/u1Blsyf

Comment: Something like this [marquee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59034753/3110834)?

Comment: In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59568979/3110834) I've shown a marquee using WebBrowser control in Windows Forms.